# Combine keys and values in RUBY

Tags: ruby

Given a hash:

```
{:a => "123", :b => "345", :c => "678", :d => "910"}
```

Write a code that generates an array that combines the keys and values. So the resulting array should be:

```
["a123", "b345", "c678", "d910"]
```

Comment: Have you at least *attempted* a solution?  Do you know how to iterate over a hash's key-value pairs?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's clearly homework.

Comment: @Rogeriopvl, why do you say it's "clearly homework". If it is, why would that be "off-topic"? Is there a SO policy that homework questions are not to be answered?

Comment: @rogeriopvl:  You shouldn't close a question *just because* it's homework.

Comment: take a look at  Enumerable, specifically the map/collect methods  (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-map).

Comment: 1. You want to combine a symbol (e.g., `:a`) and string (e.g.,`'123"`) to form another string. To do that you must first transform the symbol to a string, then you must combine the two strings into one. 2. You need a way to access each key-value pair of the hash (e.g., `:a` and `"123"`, so that you can perform #1.  For #2, investigate the method [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map). The class `Hash` `include`s the `Enumerable` module, so `Enumerable` methods (such as `map`) can be sent to `Hash` instances.

Comment: @CarySwoveland the user asking the question did not provide any proof that it was trying to solve the problem. And the question text is written as a programming exercise.

Comment: @rogeriopvl, when I began learning Ruby I had many practice questions like this one, and none were homework.  Moreover, while some SO members demand that the OP provide code to show that he or she has attempted to solve the problem (except, of course, when the OP has high-rep, in which case the "requirement" is *always* waived), others give the benefit of doubt to the OP, and when the OP hasn't a clue how to approach the problem, believe it is silly to demand to see code, however artificial it might be.

Comment: To clarify this is not a homework assignment as @rogeriopvl had stated. This is from exercises that my friend gave me to practice because im trying to learn Ruby on my own online. 

Also I've been trying to solve this exercise for a few hours now but im having trouble getting started even after searching for possible solution on stackoverflow. Most of the solutions or similar solutions were to complicated for my understanding.

Comment: Thanks for showing my how to approach it @CarySwoveland. Working on it right now

Comment: I was incorrect when I said that, when combining a symbol and a string, you must first convert the symbol to a string. (See, e.g., @spickerman's answer and Chris' comment.) However, since you are just learning Ruby, I think it is useful to think of the conversion of the symbol to a string as a separate step.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
{:a => "123", :b => "345", :c => "678", :d => "910"}.map { |k, v| "#{k}#{v}" }
#=> ["a123", "b345", "c678", "d910"]
```

Comment: I'd have gone with `arr.map(&:join)` personally.

Comment: @Chris, that's interesting; I didn't know [Array#join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join) converted symbols to strings, but it does make sense. In fact, it converts all elements to strings and even seems to flatten arrays: `[{d: :e}, [:a, [:b, :c]] , 's'].join #=> "{:d=>:e}abcs"`.